# .APK upload failed

Tags: android, upload, apk, google-play

Answered by me bellow

When I try to upload my .APK file i get this error:

Upload failed

I have tried cleaning my project, exporting it, and running it about 100 times over a span of almost 24 hours.  This is just an updated version of my .APK.  I have already successfully uploaded several updated .APK to the play store.  I changed the Version and I am using the same keystore for this update as I have for all my other updates.  Any suggestions?  And sorry that this isn't a code specific problem.  Also I only made a small edit to one of my activities.

Comment: Maybe upload using another connection? Maybe your connection is awful?

Comment: Also try a different browser. On the old interface, it would error out on Chrome after uploading an apk, but not on IE.

Comment: All my updates have been on Chrome I will try firefox and safari now

Comment: Shutdown Firefox completely and restart it worked for me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with using Chrome. The problem is your session is invalid. Using any different browser such as Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera, etc. would create a new session and allow the upload to work.

The real solution is to just log out and back in because whatever data Google uses to verify the upload is no longer valid, but they still allow you to navigate throughout your developer account like you are logged in with a valid session.

Comment: Great solution. Found the true problem instead of simply blaming the browser.

Comment: I am using Firefox and this worked for me.  Thanks!  I just logged out and logged back in.

Comment: The true problem is that this isnt handled properly by the google developer console. This is just another workaround..

Comment: I have tried 2 different OS, 3 different browsers and 2 different internet connections. Yet, my problem still exists. I can not update my app.

Comment: I just logged out and back in using chrome and this did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Thank you A-C

The solution to this problem was to use **firefox** instead of **chrome**

Comment: @EGHDK This is one of the oddest problems I've come across when using the dev console. I find it ironic that Google's own browser causes issues. But hey, at least it worked for the OP :)

Comment: So strange, worked for me. Is it the new interface causing this?

Comment: Chrome was failing for me too.   But then I got it to work from a Chrome Incognito tab.

Comment: WOW! Thanks @John! That worked perfectly. It failed in Chrome 6 times. Then I open an incognito window, go straight to https://play.google.com/apps/publish , and login. Upload succeeded. Insane, but still better than my iOS experience.

Comment: If you encounter this problem, try using Firefox. It took me many days to figure that out! I'm now using Firefox for any APK upload, I'm getting tired of uploading my 8 Mb application several times only to show the process fail and fail again.

Comment: Heh, it failed in Firefox for me, but worked in Chrome. Very odd. Seems to be a cookie issue.

Comment: See the answer from mtg169 for the true solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's not your browser. Log out and log back in again, a simple page refresh won't do. Crazy I know, but it works. You'll also find your images will fail to upload without an error message.

Comment: A simple page refresh was sufficient for me so there may be different cases.  I'd had the tab open for a long time (weeks) and then immediately went to upload (which failed).

Comment: Likely this issue has now been fixed. I suspect the session might have ended, and the front end not been made aware of it.

Comment: If it doesn't fix it, at least it will show you the REAL error next time you login

Answer (score 2):

For me, trying to logout and login again to my account solved the problem (just as mtg168 said)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

How many times have you tried?
I usually get that once in a while, and when I get it I might get it 4-5 times in a row. Play Store just sucks some times.

Retry and it should work!;o

Comment: Tried a bunch of times over a span of almost 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be that your session has expired.  I just ran into the same problem, but when I logged out and then logged back in, the upload worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to specifiy a version name different than the one provided in version 2?

Comment: Nah, you can have the same version name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I happened to change the login password before uploading the apk. Sign out and Sign back in again did help.

Answer (score 0):

For me it ended being related to a newline character in my strings.xml

No error message was shown for ~8 tries then it appeared randomly. Was able to upload after changing the newline character to \n from \u000d