# GPG services test without upload new apk signed to google play

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have game app and my app also registered with app sign services. And I have two SHA-1 certificate fingerprint once is App signing certificate and another is Upload certificate. My app is going to update new version but during develop and test I meet problem with connection fail.I need to upload every new app apk and new version code to google play console to be pass that connection. I really felt bad about it.Do anyone have solution?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking... can you try to clarify please? For instance, does "_but during develop and test I meet problem with connection fail_" mean the _application being developed_ has a connection problem (while it is running) or that _your computer_ (on which you're developing the app) has a connection problem and you are unable to upload new versions?

Comment: It mean the first version of app has been published on google play so far, it worked fine with gpg connection. But about next version, connection worked unless I uploaded it to google play console. My problem is if i want test the second version of my app i needed upload apk to console  wait until it publised. And I just want to know if have other way? because it take me to long to wait and i need to update version code of app.

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186917/apk-upload-failed).

This is just one of the answer.

> The problem has nothing to do with using Chrome. The problem is your
>   session is invalid. Using any different browser such as Firefox,
>   Internet Explorer, Opera, etc. would create a new session and allow
>   the upload to work.
>
> The real solution is to just log out and back in because whatever data
>   Google uses to verify the upload is no longer valid, but they still
>   allow you to navigate throughout your developer account like you are
>   logged in with a valid session.

For further details visit the [Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en&ref_topic=7072031)

Hope it solves your problem.