# Invalid APK file error while uploading to play store

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, apk

I am trying to upload an APK file to google play store. I am facing 'Your apk is Invalid' error.

I have created the APK using Android studio.

It's just a Webview app

I have latest version of Chrome installed.

Tried with Mozilla as well.

Cleared the cache as well.

Is there any other point missed ?

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and post `build.gradle` (app level) file, screenshot of the error?

Comment: I dont have build gradle file (app level) with me right now. However, let me know if you can guess any issue generally happen with that. Attached error screen though.

Comment: Problem can be anything. It's hard to guess the cause for the error. Check these StackOverflow questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18097504/5180017), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6273892/5180017), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24336321/5180017), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17397195/5180017)

Comment: My issue is resolved now. It was a mistake from my end only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just mention the steps here for successfully uploading the .apk file

a) Create the app using android studio and test it on the emulator.

b) Generate a signed apk.  While creating apk file, a jks file will be mentioned in android studio on the screen where you provide path and password, etc. However, after generation of signed apk is complete, you can find the .apk file by clicking on 'Locate' option. This 'locate' will take you to release folder where your actual .apk file will be there.

c) Upload that .apk to play store by normal approach.

d) If somehow, next time you forget the keystore, unpublish this app on play store.

e) You can create a new .apk file by changing the package name and application id (refactoring). And then again generate the signed apk that can be located in release folder (by clicking on 'locate' after apk generation).

f) You can then create a new release in play store from the apk created in above step 'e' (using new pkg name and application id).

g) If you then want to update the .apk in play store, then update the Version code and number in the android project. Then generate a new signed apk that can be updated in google play store.

You can find every step in details somewhere in google but this is the overall process.

Answer (score 0):

Try the suggestions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186917/apk-upload-failed).

> The problem has nothing to do with using Chrome. The problem is your session is invalid. Using any different browser such as Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera, etc. would create a new session and allow the upload to work.
>
> The real solution is to just log out and back in because whatever data Google uses to verify the upload is no longer valid, but they still allow you to navigate throughout your developer account like you are logged in with a valid session.

You may also check the workarounds in this [blog](https://www.androidpit.com/forum/563730/how-to-fix-package-file-is-invalid-error).

Answer (score 0):

The APK you upload is an invalid zip file. Without seeing the APK unfortunately, it's hard to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: My issue is resolved now. It was a mistake from my end only.